# Matlab repmat function equivalent in c++

Tags: c++, api, matlab

Is there an  equivalent in c++(in any API/library) for Matlab [repmat](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No because there is no standard C++ matrix class to replicate. If you use a third-party matrix library (many exist), you may find it has that function available, but if you roll your own matrix class, you'll need to supply this function too.

Comment: any freely available third party matrix libraries you can suggest?

Comment: @iceman Yes, per my answer below, I have been using GSL. It's a C library, but you can just wrap it (there's even GSLWrap, if you want to use that). It's quite featureful. Then there's LAPACK and BLAS, but if I understand correctly, GSL uses those?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Matrices.html) and I have something like this:

```
gsl_matrix * RepMatHorizAlloc(gsl_vector * v, size_t k) {
  gsl_matrix *mat = gsl_matrix_alloc(k, v->size);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    gsl_matrix_set_row(mat, i, v);
  }
  return mat;
}

gsl_matrix * RepMatVertAlloc(gsl_vector * v, size_t k) {
  gsl_matrix *mat = gsl_matrix_alloc(v->size, k);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    gsl_matrix_set_col(mat, i, v);
  }
  return mat;
}
```